# ManyToMany Relation using Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code on models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    mov = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mov

class Atrib(models.Model):
    atrib = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.atrib

class Dict(models.Model):
    atrib = models.ForeignKey(Atrib)
    dictionary = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name = 'dictionary')
```

I want to load a defaultdict like this: `{attribute1:[movie1, movie2, ...], atribute2:[movie2, movie3,...] ... }` using Django.

First of all, I added all the attributes of the dictionary using the Atrib class.
Now I need to add, for every attribute, the related movies. I tried to do the following, considering only one attribute (just testing):

```
attribute1 = Atrib(atrib = atribs)

for m in dictionary[attribute]:
    m = Movie(mov = m)
    m.save()
    attribute1.dictionary.add(m)
```

It shows me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Atrib' object has no attribute 'dictionary'.
```

Am I doing the models correctly for this type of dictionary? And why is this error occurring? I am new in Django and I am a little lost!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to save `attribute1 = Atrib(atrib = atribs)`
do `attribute1.save()`

Next, after `Attribute` object creation you don't have `Dictionary` object related to it.
You need to create it first, set it to this object and then you will have ability to operations you want.

Note: to access `attribute.dict` you need OneToOne relationship, not ForeignKey.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it! I saved the attributes already, and have all of them. Now, I need to change atrib to `atrib = models.OneToOneField(Atrib)`, right? What I don't understand is how to associate the attribute to the movies, how could I relate Dictionary with the attributes?

Comment: If uou have Dict, associated with Atrib, you can access it by `attr_obj.dict`. And then you can add movies accessing `attr_obj.dict.dictionary.add()`, if I understand you right.

Comment: I think I don't have it,  I just added the attributes and have no idea how to link them as the keys of a dictionary! So i can reconstruct `{attribute:[list of movies]}`. The only thing I managed to do at the moment was to load the attributes. So I have in the Admin page all of them.